# Opening multiple kernels in command line for batch operation

Tags: kernel

I have been searching around for a while, and perhaps I'm just using the wrong terminology, but I haven't found a way to do this.

I have a mathematica notebook converted and saved as nobel_test.m, which runs perfectly on my own computer. Because it takes about an hour to run, I'm trying to run multiple at one time on a computer cluster that can have 100 instances going at once (named nobel). I converted my original notebook by making everything InputForm, ending with Exit[], etc, and changing outputs so that they are saved in external text files instead of printing into the notebook.

When I tested this, it ran fine by itself - the script ran, read the correct contents, created and printed the files it needed to, etc. I used the command

```
math -noprompt -run "<<nobel_test.m"
```

I also tried

```
math -noprompt -script "nobel_test.m"
```

which also works for single cases.

However, the banner opens ("The following versions are available...mathematica-8.0.4.." etc.), and while no In[1]:= or anything like that prints, it seems to enter an input-less front end that can't be closed (without quitting the kernel). It automatically closes about an hour later when the notebook finishes evaluating.

Because of this, I can only run sequentially, rather than in parallel. I thought -noprompt was supposed to prevent the banner from opening, so that you could just submit job after job to the max of your licenses; but because it opens and holds there, I have to wait until the current job is done before starting a new one.

Is there a way to quit that section without closing the kernel, or other good ways to execute several mathematica scripts at once?

Again, apologies if this is commonly asked, I'm probably not searching the correct things. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't follow the second part of your question.  I've never seen a message like "The following versions are available...mathematica-8.0.4..".  Can you elaborate on that a bit more and show exactly what happens?  Is it possible that it is not Mathematica itself that gives that message but some version selector software specific to your HPC cluster?

Comment: (On out HPC cluster I need to explicitly make available the specific version of a program I want to use by doing something like `module load mathematica/9.0.1`)

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8WBcr7n.png

Comment: I can exit with ctrl-z, but that appears to quit the entire kernel; I'm trying to just get another prompt so that I can run a second notebook.

Comment: Normal one (i.e. just math) looks like this: http://imgur.com/ZCWyULq

Comment: It looks like the mathematica launch script was modified on your system.  That message is not printed by mathematica itself.

Comment: Hi there, are you running on linux? If so have you tried using `MathKernel` and putting the command in the background using '&' ? For example : `MathKernel -script  myscript.m &` . The commands you want to run in the m file are marked as initialisation cells ?

Comment: ah, that worked! I didn't know about the & command. Thank you very much!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it relates to the operation of shells on Unix/Linux in general, rather than to *Mathematica* itself.

Comment: @image_doctor herm, so is math an alias for the MathKernel on linux systems not? Anyway I like your comment.

Comment: I feel this question should not be forgotten too easily. Personally I don't like `Parallelize` much. I feel methods to run computations bluntly in parallel are very welcome, even if that involves some operating system specific content.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom do you propose to answer with image_doctor's comment and CW it?

Comment: @bobthechemist I was being indecisive and was contemplating making a new question that dealt with all the major OSes. But I like this too and it is less of a hassle :).

Answer (score 3):

From image_docter's comment:

If you are running on Linux then you may try using `MathKernel` and putting the command in the background using '&' ? For example :

```
MathKernel -script myscript.m &
```